# Smooth scroll to section of other webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click on a link on page 1. I want the following to happen:

1. Open page 2 at the top
2. Smoothly scroll to a given location on page 2

How would I go about setting this up?
I have managed to make clicking a link on a single page smoothly scroll to a given location on that page, but do not know how to do this between pages.

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far? Please check [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So you want to open "page 2" but have it scroll to a specific point on that page? I think it would be a good idea if you share the relevant source code for your "smooth scrolling" unless you expect others to rewrite it to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use hashtag link to move focus any specific link on page. It works fine for other pages.

You can provide the page2.html#linkname in page1 link that will open page2 and move focus to mentioned link.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the behaviour of [`scroll-behaviour: smooth;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) in compatible browsers (currently Firefox and Chrome).
All other browser will not animate but the links still work. That is a perfect example of [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).